# Undefined property: stdClass

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm getting the following error on these lines

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$id on line 36
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$id on line 40
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$screen_name on line 40

Line 36:

```
$vOAuth1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `atwitter_oauth_users` WHERE `oauth_provider` = 'twitter' AND `oauth_uid` = '{$oUserInfo->id}'"); // searching for user in database
```

Line 40:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `atwitter_oauth_users` (`oauth_provider`, `oauth_uid`, `username`, `oauth_token`, `oauth_secret`) VALUES ('twitter', {$oUserInfo->id}, '{$oUserInfo->screen_name}', '{$aAccessToken['oauth_token']}', '{$aAccessToken['oauth_token_secret']}')");
```

This is the whole code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

require_once('inc/header.php');
require_once('inc/twitteroauth.php');

global $sConsumerKey, $sConsumerSecret;

session_start();

if (! empty($_GET['oauth_verifier']) && ! empty($_SESSION['oauth_token']) && ! empty($_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'])) {
} else { // some params missed, back to login page
    header('Location: http://www.domain.com/livetweeter/tw_login.php');
    echo "parameters missed";
}

$oTwitterOauth = new TwitterOAuth($sConsumerKey, $sConsumerSecret, $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

$aAccessToken = $oTwitterOauth->getAccessToken($_GET['oauth_verifier']); // get access tokens

$_SESSION['access_token'] = $aAccessToken; // saving access token to sessions

$oUserInfo = $oTwitterOauth->get('account/verify_credentials'); // get account details

if(isset($oUserInfo->error)){
    header('Location: http://www.domain.com/livetweeter/tw_login.php'); // in case of any errors - back to login page
    echo "error";
} else {
    global $sDbName, $sDbUserName, $sDbUserPass;
    $vLink = mysql_connect($sDbHost, $sDbUserName, $sDbUserPass);
    mysql_select_db($sDbName);

    $vOAuth1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `atwitter_oauth_users` WHERE `oauth_provider` = 'twitter' AND `oauth_uid` = '{$oUserInfo->id}'"); // searching for user in database
    $aOauthUserInfo = mysql_fetch_array($vOAuth1);

    if (empty($aOauthUserInfo)) { // if user info not present - add them into database
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `atwitter_oauth_users` (`oauth_provider`, `oauth_uid`, `username`, `oauth_token`, `oauth_secret`) VALUES ('twitter', {$oUserInfo->id}, '{$oUserInfo->screen_name}', '{$aAccessToken['oauth_token']}', '{$aAccessToken['oauth_token_secret']}')");
        $vOAuth2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `atwitter_oauth_users` WHERE `id` = '" . mysql_insert_id() . "'");
        $aOauthUserInfo = mysql_fetch_array($vOAuth2);
    } else {
        mysql_query("UPDATE `atwitter_oauth_users` SET `oauth_token` = '{$aAccessToken['oauth_token']}', `oauth_secret` = '{$aAccessToken['oauth_token_secret']}' WHERE `oauth_provider` = 'twitter' AND `oauth_uid` = '{$oUserInfo->id}'"); // update tokens
    }

    $_SESSION['oauth_id'] = $aOauthUserInfo['id'];
    $_SESSION['oauth_username'] = $aOauthUserInfo['username'];
    $_SESSION['oauth_uid'] = $aOauthUserInfo['oauth_uid'];
    $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = $aOauthUserInfo['oauth_provider'];
    $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $aOauthUserInfo['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['oauth_secret'] = $aOauthUserInfo['oauth_secret'];

    mysql_close($vLink);

    header('Location: http://www.domain.com/livetweeter/index.php');
    echo "we've got an error";
}

if(!empty($_SESSION['oauth_username'])){
    header('Location: http://www.domain.com/livetweeter/index.php'); // already logged, back to our main page
    echo "this is an error";
}

?>
```

*Note: I know I shouldn't be using `mysql_query` - I'll sort that once I have to script working.*

Comment: Debug `var_dump($oUserInfo)` (just after the declaration) what output do you get?

Comment: There's our answer! `The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.`